# Gradle project sync failed because Signature for method that resolves Paths was not found?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, groovy

I have downloaded the rxc project from Github, from here
https://github.com/x0b/rcx

When I open the project in Android Studio it attempts to sync but fails with the following error:

```
 Build file '/home/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/rcx/rclone/build.gradle' line: 80

A problem occurred evaluating project ':rclone'.
> No signature of method: java.lang.String.resolve() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [source.properties]
  Possible solutions: reverse(), split(java.lang.String), replace(java.util.Map)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':rclone'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:277)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:291)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:721)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:151)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:69)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:46)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:57)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:226)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:163)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:148)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:77)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.resolve() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [source.properties]
Possible solutions: reverse(), split(java.lang.String), replace(java.util.Map)
    at build_7jiv9w8pxhgidce7ka8jpvvft.checkNdk(/home/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/rcx/rclone/build.gradle:80)
    at build_7jiv9w8pxhgidce7ka8jpvvft$checkNdk.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_7jiv9w8pxhgidce7ka8jpvvft.configureNdk(/home/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/rcx/rclone/build.gradle:68)
    at build_7jiv9w8pxhgidce7ka8jpvvft.run(/home/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/rcx/rclone/build.gradle:96)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 141 more
```

What I see is that Gradle / Groovy can't seem to find the right Method signature for the Method java.lang.String.resolve(String other). Other than invalidating caches I don't know what to do.

The gradle.build file where the error happens (gradle.build file for the rclone dependency of this project):

```
    // This is the rclone build script. It can build rclone binaries for any target
// architecture on any target architecture.
//
// Supported Android targets:
//  - arm-v8a (64 bit arm)
//  - arm-v7a (32 bit arm7)
//  - x86 (32 bit)
//  - x64 (64 bit)
//
// Supported host systems:
//  - linux x64
//  - mac os x64
//  - windows x64
//  - windows x86 (with NDK 21b installed)
//
// Prerequisits:
//  - go 1.14 - go 1.16
//  - ndk

// Rclone version - any git reference (tag, branch, hash) should work
def buildTag = 'v1.55.1'
ext.ndkVersion = '22.1.7171670'

//
// DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING BELOW
//
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.util.Properties

def configureNdk() {
    def osName = System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase()
    def osArch = System.properties['os.arch']

    def os = ''
    if (osName.contains('windows')) {
        if(osArch.equals('amd64')) {
            os = "windows-x86_64"
        } else if (osArch.equals('x86')) {
            // NDK has dropped x86 windows support in NDK 21 and greater. This
            // may break at for any reason when the golang tolchain is
            // upgraded.
            os = "windows"
            ext.ndkVersion = '20.1.5948944'
        }
    } else if (osName.contains("linux")) {
        os = "linux-x86_64"
    } else if (osName.contains('mac')) {
        os = "darwin-x86_64"
    } else {
        throw new GradleException("OS=${osName}/ARCH=${osArch} not supported")
    }

    // locate NDK
    def androidNdkHome = System.getenv('ANDROID_NDK_HOME')
    def androidHome = System.getenv('ANDROID_HOME')
    def ndkBasePath
    if (androidHome != null) {
        def canonicalPath = Paths.get(androidHome, 'ndk', ext.ndkVersion)
        def bundlePath = Paths.get(androidHome, 'ndk-bundle')
        if (Files.exists(canonicalPath) && checkNdk(canonicalPath)) {
            ndkBasePath = canonicalPath;
        } else if (Files.exists(bundlePath) && checkNdk(bundlePath)) {
            ndkBasePath = bundlePath;
        }
    } else if (androidNdkHome != null && checkNdk(androidNdkHome)) {
        ndkBasePath = Paths.get(androidNdkHome)
    }

    if (ndkBasePath == null) {
        throw GradleException("NDK ${ext.ndkVersion} not found")
    }

    return ndkBasePath.resolve(Paths.get('toolchains', 'llvm', 'prebuilt', os, 'bin'))
}

def checkNdk(ndkBasePath) {
    def propertiesPath = ndkBasePath.resolve('source.properties')
    def ndkProperties = new Properties()
    ndkProperties.load(file(propertiesPath).newReader())
    return ndkProperties['Pkg.Revision'] == ext.ndkVersion
}

def configureGo() {
    def localGo = Paths.get('golang/go/bin/go')
    return Files.exists(localGo) ? localGo : 'go'
}

def repository = 'github.com/rclone/rclone'
def repositoryRef = repository + '@' + buildTag
def ldflags = "-X github.com/rclone/rclone/fs.Version=${buildTag}-rcx"
def goPath = Paths.get(projectDir.absolutePath, 'gopath').toAbsolutePath().toString()
def appLibPath = Paths.get(projectDir.absolutePath, '../app/lib').toAbsolutePath().toString()
def ndkPrefix = configureNdk()
def goBinary = configureGo()


task fetchRclone(type: Exec) {
    mkdir "gopath"
    environment 'GOPATH', goPath
    environment "GO111MODULE", "on"
    commandLine 'go', 'get', '-d', repositoryRef

    ignoreExitValue true
    errorOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    doLast {
        if (execResult.getExitValue() != 0) {
            throw new GradleException("Error running go get: \n${errorOutput.toString()}")
        }
    }
}

task cleanNative {
    enabled = false
    doLast {
        delete "${appLibPath}/armeabi-v7a/librclone.so"
        delete "${appLibPath}/arm64-v8a/librclone.so"
        delete "${appLibPath}/x86/librclone.so"
        delete "${appLibPath}/x86_64/librclone.so"
    }
}

task buildArm(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn fetchRclone
    environment 'GOPATH', goPath
    def crossCompiler = ndkPrefix.resolve('armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang')
    environment 'CC', crossCompiler
    environment 'CC_FOR_TARGET', crossCompiler
    environment 'GOOS', 'android'
    environment 'GOARCH', 'arm'
    environment 'GOARM', '7'
    environment 'CGO_ENABLED', '1'
    environment 'CGO_LDFLAGS', "-fuse-ld=lld -s"
    workingDir Paths.get(goPath, "pkg/mod/${repositoryRef}".split('/'))
    def artifactTarget = "${appLibPath}/armeabi-v7a/librclone.so"
    commandLine 'go', 'build', '-v', '-tags', 'android noselfupdate', '-trimpath', '-ldflags', ldflags, '-o', artifactTarget, '.'

    ignoreExitValue true
    errorOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    doLast {
        if (execResult.getExitValue() != 0) {
            throw new GradleException("Error running go build: \n${errorOutput.toString()}")
        }
    }
}

task buildArm64(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn fetchRclone
    environment 'GOPATH', goPath
    def crossCompiler = ndkPrefix.resolve('aarch64-linux-android21-clang')
    environment 'CC', crossCompiler
    environment 'CC_FOR_TARGET', crossCompiler
    environment 'GOOS', 'android'
    environment 'GOARCH', 'arm64'
    environment 'CGO_ENABLED', '1'
    environment 'CGO_LDFLAGS', "-fuse-ld=lld -s"
    workingDir Paths.get(goPath, "pkg/mod/${repositoryRef}".split('/'))
    def artifactTarget = "${appLibPath}/arm64-v8a/librclone.so"
    commandLine 'go', 'build', '-v', '-tags', 'android noselfupdate', '-trimpath', '-ldflags', ldflags, '-o', artifactTarget, '.'}

task buildx86(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn fetchRclone
    environment 'GOPATH', goPath
    def crossCompiler = ndkPrefix.resolve('i686-linux-android21-clang')
    environment 'CC', crossCompiler
    environment 'CC_FOR_TARGET', crossCompiler
    environment 'GOOS', 'android'
    environment 'GOARCH', '386'
    environment 'CGO_ENABLED', '1'
    environment 'CGO_LDFLAGS', "-fuse-ld=lld -s"
    workingDir Paths.get(goPath, "pkg/mod/${repositoryRef}".split('/'))
    def artifactTarget = "${appLibPath}/x86/librclone.so"
    commandLine 'go', 'build', '-v', '-tags', 'android noselfupdate', '-trimpath', '-ldflags', ldflags, '-o', artifactTarget, '.'
}

task buildx64(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn fetchRclone
    environment 'GOPATH', goPath
    def crossCompiler = ndkPrefix.resolve('x86_64-linux-android21-clang')
    environment 'CC', crossCompiler
    environment 'CC_FOR_TARGET', crossCompiler
    environment 'GOOS', 'android'
    environment 'GOARCH', 'amd64'
    environment 'CGO_ENABLED', '1'
    environment 'CGO_LDFLAGS', "-fuse-ld=lld -s"
    workingDir Paths.get(goPath, "pkg/mod/${repositoryRef}".split('/'))
    def artifactTarget = "${appLibPath}/x86_64/librclone.so"
    commandLine 'go', 'build', '-v', '-tags', 'android noselfupdate', '-trimpath', '-ldflags', ldflags, '-o', artifactTarget, '.'
}

task buildNative {
    dependsOn fetchRclone
    dependsOn buildArm
    dependsOn buildArm64
    dependsOn buildx86
    dependsOn buildx64
}

task prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel {
    // ignore, does not build from kotlin sources
}

buildNative.mustRunAfter(buildArm, buildArm64, buildx86, buildx64)
defaultTasks 'buildNative'
```

And the actual place where the resolve() method is:

```
def checkNdk(ndkBasePath) {
    def propertiesPath = ndkBasePath.resolve('source.properties') //here
    def ndkProperties = new Properties()
    ndkProperties.load(file(propertiesPath).newReader())
    return ndkProperties['Pkg.Revision'] == ext.ndkVersion
}
```

**Relevant Information**
OS: Pop!_OS 21.04 / ubuntu debian
IDE: Android Studio 4.2.2
Android Gradle Plugin: 4.2.1
Gradle: 6.9
NDK: 22.1.7171670
Android SDK: 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is probably a better fit for the projects' issue tracker.

Though this build script was written by someone who does not have much knowledge about either gradle or groovy - me. I think this is a bug in the build script. Replace `checkNdk(androidNdkHome)` with `checkNdk(Paths.get(androidNdkHome))`.

Alternatively, you can also configure `$ANDROID_HOME` to point to your Android SDK installation and then make sure that NDK 22b is installed to `$ANDROID_HOME\ndk\22.1.7171670` or `$ANDROID_HOME\ndk-bundle`.